# ¿Como rellenar RecyclerView de un fragmento a partir de un Async Task con un custom adapter?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragment, android-asynctask, android-recyclerview

Actualmente tengo las siguientes clases:

## CategoryFragment.java

```java
public class CategoryFragment extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "category_name";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private int mParam1;

    public CategoryFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @return A new instance of fragment CategoryFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static CategoryFragment newInstance(int param1) {
        CategoryFragment fragment = new CategoryFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PARAM1);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Context context = getActivity();
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listado_noticias, container, false);
        RecyclerView rw_noticias = view.findViewById(R.id.rw_noticias);

        new LoadArticlesTask().execute(MainScreen.mPrefs,MainScreen.hasRemember,view,context,rw_noticias);


        return null;
    }

}
```

## listado_noticias.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rw_noticias"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

## LoadArticlesTask.java

```java
public class LoadArticlesTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, List<Article>> {
    
    private static final String TAG = "LoadArticlesTask";
    private View view;
    private Context context;
    private RecyclerView rw_noticias;

    @Override
    protected List<Article> doInBackground(Object... params) {
        SharedPreferences sp = (SharedPreferences)params[0];
        boolean hasRemember = (boolean)params[1];
        view = (View)params[2];
        context = (Context)params[3];
        rw_noticias = (RecyclerView)params[4];
        List<Article> res = null;
        Properties ini = new Properties();
        ini.setProperty(RESTConnection.ATTR_SERVICE_URL,Constants.URL_SERVICE);
        ini.setProperty(RESTConnection.ATTR_REQUIRE_SELF_CERT,Constants.CERT_VALUE);
        ModelManager.configureConnection(ini);
        String strIdUser;
        String strApiKey;
        String strIdAuthUser;

        if(hasRemember){
            strIdUser = sp.getString("pref_apikey","");
            strApiKey = sp.getString("pref_IdUser","");
            strIdAuthUser = sp.getString("pref_strIdAuthUser","");

        }else {
            strIdUser = ModelManager.getLoggedIdUSer();
            strApiKey = ModelManager.getLoggedApiKey();
            strIdAuthUser = ModelManager.getLoggedAuthType();
        }
        //ModelManager uses singleton pattern, connecting once per app execution in enough
        if (!ModelManager.isConnected()){
            // if it is the first login
            if (strIdUser==null || strIdUser.equals("")) {
                try {
                    ModelManager.login(Constants.USER, Constants.PASS);

                } catch (AuthenticationError e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                }
            }
            // if we have saved user credentials from previous connections
            else{
                ModelManager.stayloggedin(strIdUser,strApiKey,strIdAuthUser);
            }
        }
        //If connection has been successful
        if (ModelManager.isConnected()) {
            try {
                // obtain 6 articles from offset 0
                res = ModelManager.getArticles(6, 0);
                for (Article article : res) {
                    // We print articles in Log
                    Log.i(TAG, String.valueOf(article));
                }
            } catch (ServerCommunicationError e) {
                Log.e(TAG,e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        return res;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Article> articles) {
        super.onPostExecute(articles);
        Log.i("Articles", articles.toString());
        for (Article article : articles) {
            // We print articles in Log
            Log.i("Articles", String.valueOf(article));
        }
        refreshList(articles,view);
    }

    public void refreshList(List<Article> data, View view){
        if (data == null){
            return;
        }
        for (Article article : data) {
            // We print articles in Log
            Log.i("Articles_rl", String.valueOf(article));
        }
        final LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
        layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        rw_noticias.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        ArticlesAdapter articlesAdapter = new ArticlesAdapter(data);
        rw_noticias.setAdapter(articlesAdapter);
        ((ArticlesAdapter)rw_noticias.getAdapter()).updateData(data);

    }


}
```

## ArticlesAdapter.java

```java
public class ArticlesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ArticlesAdapter.ArticleViewHolder>{

    private List<Article> articulos;
    public ArticlesAdapter(List<Article> articulos){
        this.articulos = articulos;
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ArticleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_layout_article, parent, false);
        return new ArticleViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ArticleViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Bitmap imagen = null;
        holder.category.setText(articulos.get(position).getCategory());
        holder.title.setText(articulos.get(position).getTitleText());
        holder.resumen.setText(articulos.get(position).getAbstractText());
        try {
            imagen = SerializationUtils.base64StringToImg(articulos.get(position).getImage().getImage());
        } catch (ServerCommunicationError serverCommunicationError) {
            serverCommunicationError.printStackTrace();
        }
        holder.thumbnail.setImageBitmap(imagen);


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return articulos.size();
    }
    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }


    public void updateData(List<Article>data){
        articulos.clear();
        articulos.addAll(data);
        notifyDataSetChanged(); //notify to repaint the list
    }

    public void articlesFilterCategory(String category){
        for (Article a : articulos){
            if(!category.equals("ALL") && !a.getCategory().equals(category)){
                articulos.remove(a);
            }
        }
    }



    public static class ArticleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        CardView cv;
        TextView category;
        TextView title;
        TextView resumen;
        ImageView thumbnail;

        public ArticleViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            cv = (CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_article);
            category = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.category_noticia);
            resumen = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.resumen_noticia);
            thumbnail = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        }
    }

}
```

## card_layout_article.xml

```xml
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:id="@+id/card_article"
    >


      <RelativeLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:paddingBottom="16dp"
          android:paddingHorizontal="1dp">


          <ImageView
              android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="231dp"
              android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
              android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
              android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
              android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
              android:adjustViewBounds="true"
              android:background="@drawable/a15877171854035"
              android:cropToPadding="true"
              android:scaleType="fitXY"
              android:src="@drawable/degradado" />

          <View
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="233dp"
              android:background="@drawable/degradado" />

          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/title_noticia"
              android:layout_width="193dp"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/thumbnail"
              android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
              android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
              android:layout_marginStart="107dp"
              android:layout_marginEnd="107dp"
              android:layout_marginBottom="95dp"
              android:text="Nuevo caso de coronavirus"
              android:textAlignment="center"
              android:textColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
              android:textSize="20dp"
              android:textStyle="bold" />

          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/category_noticia"
              android:layout_width="91dp"
              android:layout_height="31dp"
              android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/thumbnail"
              android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
              android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
              android:layout_marginStart="11dp"
              android:layout_marginEnd="316dp"
              android:layout_marginBottom="145dp"
              android:text="NATIONAL"
              android:textAlignment="center"
              android:textColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
              android:textSize="15dp"
              android:textStyle="bold" />

          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/resumen_noticia"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="90dp"
              android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/thumbnail"
              android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
              android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
              android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
              android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
              android:layout_marginBottom="-1dp"
              android:text="Nuevo caso de coronavirus"
              android:textAlignment="viewStart"
              android:textColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
              android:textSize="11dp"
              android:textStyle="bold" />


      </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

En el log.i que tengo en el post execute del async task puedo ver como los articulos si que se me estan cogiendo bien del servicio web y los puedo ver con el toString que tengo en Article.java, sin embargo no se porque motivo luego no consigo que se visualicen e inserten bien en el recyclerview del fragmento.

[Captura de la activity con fragmento y recyclerview vacio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0caUP.png)

Gracias.

Comment: Estás añadiendo datos al adapter dos veces cada vez que se ejecuta el método refreshList.  Para esto, instancia el adapter fuera de este método sin ninguna lista por constructor y, cuando recibas los datos, llamas a tu adapter para que actualice la lista y haga un notifyDataSetChanged.  No the hace falta castear el adapter desde el recyclerview para esto y diría que no necesitas el método onAttachedToRecyclerView, ya que no estás haciendo nada.

Answer (score 0):

Para recargar los datos debes usar el método [adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged())

> [notifyDataSetChanged()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()) Notifica a los observadores adjuntos que
>   los datos subyacentes han cambiado y que cualquier Vista que refleje
>   el conjunto de datos debería actualizarse.

Por lo tanto después de actualizar los datos usa el método:

```
 ((ArticlesAdapter)rw_noticias.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
```

De hecho este método ya lo estas usando

```
public void refreshList(List<Article> data, View view){
    if (data == null){
        return;
    }
    for (Article article : data) {
        // We print articles in Log
        Log.i("Articles_rl", String.valueOf(article));
    }
    //final LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
    //layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    //rw_noticias.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    //ArticlesAdapter articlesAdapter = new ArticlesAdapter(data);
    rw_noticias.setAdapter(articlesAdapter);
    ((ArticlesAdapter)rw_noticias.getAdapter()).updateData(data);

}
```